# RegionPlot (or otherwise) with exclusions

Tags: plotting, regions

I would like to plot something like (just a little toy example, I have many of these):

```
RegionPlot[x != 1 \[And] -5 < y < 9, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

I know that `RegionPlot[]` does not show me the "exclusion" of `x != 1` since it does not handle points and lines.

I thought long and hard about overlapping with `ContourPlot[]`, but then I would have to parse the predicates ... not fun.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Thanx.

Comment: maybe `ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Axes -> False, 
 Exclusions -> {x == 1}]`?

Comment: Thank you, @kglr. However, as I understand you, even with your approach of `ParametricPlot[]`, I would have to parse the predicates in order to find the one-dimensional exceptions.(If I had to do that, then `ContourPlot[]` would do the trick.) The point here is to have it done automatically, apparently with functions other than `RegionPlot[]`..

Comment: How have you stored your predicates? Don't you have to anyway write that in RegionPlot[]?

Comment: I certainly have the predicates stored away in a variable. However, I would have to `Scan[]` the predicates "tree" to see which 1) are valid `Region`s, and 2) check that the two-dimensional ones are `RegionPlot[]`ed, and subsequently the one- (and zero-)dimensional ones are overlaid with the negated logic, with `White`, using `ContourPlot[]`. Therefore, I am wondering how this was done before the days of `RegionPlot[]`, which perhaps includes an `Exclusions` option.